# Добрый день, пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу, мне задали это тестовое задание на собеседовании, а я не справился

Tags: php

Придумайте и реализуйте структуру массива с помощью которого удобнее реализовать следующую задачу

С системе есть владельцы автомобилей у которых заданы (фио, email, указан год рождения)

Так же есть машины (модель машины, год выпуска и регистрационный номер)

Создайте такой массив с примерами а после выведите в виде списка

Например: Андрей, e@mail.ru, (1970) - владеет 2 машинами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [
   [
   'name' => 'Вася',
   'email' => 'e@mail.ru'
   'year' => '2001'
   'cars' => [
       [
         'model' => 'Lada'
         'year' => '2019'
         'reg_num' => 'a777aa777'
       ],
       [
         'model' => 'Lada'
         'year' => '2019'
         'reg_num' => 'a777aa777'
       ],
     ],
  ],
];

foreach($array as $owner) {
     echo $owner['name'].' владеет '.count($owner['cars']).' машинами';
}
```

Comment: либо задача криво описана, либо это должны быть 2 разных массива а не вложенный

Comment: А почему два разных? У машины может быть неколько владельцев по вашему? Вроде нет такого в законодательстве.

Comment: спасибо большое...вроде все получилось)))

Comment: @Muhammad не за что. Если ответ правильный, поставьте пожалуйста зеленую галочку и плюсик.

Comment: Эту задачу я уже виде сегодня, только там была просьба сделать на другом языке и честно говорилось, что это курсовой. Ко всем жаждущим поправить свою"карму" путем решения чужих учебных заданий, не надо ничего делать пока вопрошающий не предъявил своих личных попыток решить задачу.

Comment: Я там сказал честно что я не справился, это задание я провалил, мне просто было интересно в чем моя ошибка, вот и все

Comment: @Muhammad дабы не возникало ненужных сомнений в подобных случаях нужно обязательно выкладывать свое, пусть и неверное, решение. Это снимет все вопросы.